# How to get the used storage of Gmail mailbox by using Gmail API?

Tags: google-api, gmail-api

I've looked in the Gmail API document to find API that allows retrieving the used storage of the Gmail mailbox.

As I searched, the used storage of mailbox (total size of all emails in a mailbox) can retrieve by calculating the sum of each email message's size.

However, this way is too slow when applying for a big mailbox.

So, I wonder that do we have another API from Google that allows retrieving the used storage of a Gmail mailbox?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### You can get this formation with the Drive API v2

More specifically, with the method
[About](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v2/reference/about).

It will return you

```
  {
   "serviceName": "GMAIL",
   "bytesUsed": "805949924"
  }
```

> However, keep in mind that Drive API v2 is outdated and might get
>   deprecated in the future.